# Accessing count value in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is my query

```
select count(payment_id) from payment where booking_id='$booking_id';
```

When i run this query in phpmyadmin i get count value 2 but i want access that value..

```
$sql="select count(payment_id) from payment where booking_id='$booking_id'";
           $query = $this->db->query($sql);
           echo  $query->num_rows();
            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
  do something....
     }
```

If count is 1 then do something and if count is greater than 1 then do something...

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql count into PHP variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797335/mysql-count-into-php-variable)

Comment: Kedar, you are getting confused between COUNT() and number of rows. If you are using the COUNT() then perhaps use its value in the IF statement, OR if you want to use the same code, then remove COUNT() from your query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql="select count(payment_id) as count_value from payment where booking_id='$booking_id'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $count =  $row->count_value;
}
if($count> 0){
  do something....
}
```

count('coulme name') means, It always return result as a single row

Answer (score 0):

Count() always returns 1 row. you need to do

```
$row = $query->result();
```

and then access the value of count from there...

Answer (score 0):

This is a model function you can do it inside or return the count from the function and do the actions in your controller.

```
function count_payer($booking_id) {
    $this->db->select ( 'payment_id' );
    $this->db->from ( 'payment' );
    $this->db->where ( 'booking_id', $booking_id );

    $query = $this->db->get ();

    $value = $query->num_rows ();

    if ($value == 1) {
        // do something and return
    } else {
        // do something else and return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want payment id then the query would be:

select sql_calc_found_rows payment_id from payment where booking_id='$booking_id';

select FOUND_ROWS();